# change a value in a csv file using pandas python without knowing its index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I need to change a value in csv file without knowing its index

but by using another value in the same row

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")
        result = df[df['USERNAME'] == login.user_name]
        result = result['CARD_BALANCE'].values[0]
        if result>=20:
           a=result+100
           df.loc[df['USERNAME'] == result, "CARD_BALANCE"] = a  
           df.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)
```

THIS IS NOT WORKING. HELP ME

Comment: your code will always get index 0 or index 1 of `df`, try is that what you want? if you want a specific username then try going through each index of `df` until you find the object that has the desired username, then assigning said object to a variable, then acting on that variable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost work, you just change one line from

```
df.loc[df['USERNAME'] == result, "CARD_BALANCE"] = a
```

become

```
df.loc[df['USERNAME'] == login.user_name, "CARD_BALANCE"] = a
```